# getting mutual values of all groups in a table (SQL Server)

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

i have a table with 3 columns

id(primary key), masCode (masterCode) and detCode(detailCode)

i need to select detCodes that are repeated in all masCode groups

for example if i have this data:

```
+----+---------+----------+
| id | masCode | detCode  |
+----+---------+----------+
|  1 | 111     |   1      |
|  2 | 111     |   5      |
|  3 | 222     |   2      |
|  4 | 222     |   5      |
|  5 | 222     |   1      |
|  6 | 223     |   5      |
|  7 | 223     |   6      |
|  8 | 223     |   1      |
+----+---------+----------+
```

the result will be this:

```
+----+---------+----------+
| id | masCode | detCode  |
+----+---------+----------+
|  1 | 111     |   1      |
|  2 | 111     |   5      |
|  4 | 222     |   5      |
|  5 | 222     |   1      |
|  6 | 223     |   5      |
|  8 | 223     |   1      |
+----+---------+----------+
```

i think i can do this with dynamic Query, is there any better way to do this?
thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way.

```
declare @masCode int = (select count(distinct masCode) from YourTable)

select *
from yourTable
where detCode in (select detCode 
                 from YourTable 
                 group by detCode 
                 having count(detCode) = @masCode)
```

**[ONLINE DEMO](http://rextester.com/MCTYS49295)**

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
;with _countedDetCodes as (
    select
        *,
        -- number of masCodes for particular detCode
        count(1) over (partition by detCode) as masCodeCnt  
    from yourTable
)
select
    Id, masCode, detCode
from _countedDetCodes
where
    masCodeCnt = (select count(distinct masCode) as [Value] from yourTable)
```

Answer (score 0):

Dynamic Queries (i.e. queries that are written as text and execute by SQL 'Execute ' instruction), are generally a bad idea.

```
execute ('select * from NotExistingTable')
```

There are some reasons why. 
Your editor will not be able to help you (at least not prior to query run) to track errors in your query. When queries get complicated, this is an issue.

Another problem is that sql server cannot assume anything about the query, 
hence - it cannot bulid optimized execution plan, which usually degrades performance.

**What you are looking is fairly simple.** 
Here is one solution.

```
;with nonuniques as (
select masCode  from [YourTable]
group by masCode 
having count(*) > 1
) select id, masCode, detCode from [YourTable] t
  inner join nonuniques n on n.masCode = t.masCode
```

Answer (score 0):

here is a quick and easy solution for you:

```
drop table if exists #temp 

create table #temp
(
id      int,
masCode int,
detCode int
)

insert into #temp values 
(1,111,1)
,(2,111,5)
,(3,222,2)
,(4,222,5)
,(5,222,1)
,(6,223,5)
,(7,223,6)
,(8,223,1)

select  *
from    #temp a 
where   a.detCode in (
        select  t.detCode
        from    #temp t
        group 
        by      t.detCode
        having(count(mascode)) > 1
        )
```